# Undefined UserControl error

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, vb.net-2010

I just created a UserControl in my application, the problem I have is that every time I edit the code of UserControl I have to delete the UserControls already added to the GUI because it fails to compile.

The project / application is called Panel and UserControl called TimerPanel, which contains a couple of text boxes within a GroupBox.

The error reads

Type 'Panel.TimerPanel' is not defined.

The strange thing is that everything works OK until I edit the UserControl.

Like I said, if I delete the UserControl GUI, compiled and then added again to the GUI control, everything works OK.

I read somewhere on this forum that you must add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, and I did and it behaves the same.

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you get that error go and build the project again, see if that fixes the issue (building a project again fixes lots of errors and when you add/change a user control is needed to use it)